# Touchpad utility

Tags: hardware, touchpad, elementary-os

I'm new in the Linux area. I just installed Elementary OS, which is related to Ubuntu, and I want to know if there is a utility for my mouse pad. In Windows I had Synaptics that allowed me to scroll with my mouse pad using 2 fingers and other tricks like this. Is there a utility like this one on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a package is provided by your distribution as `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. You can either install it using your distribution's graphical package manager, or from the terminal:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

After doing so, restart your X server, and your trackpad should work as you expect.

As a side note, you can find such packages yourself by using `apt-cache search`. Since you knew the key part of the puzzle here -- that you need a synaptics driver -- the following would have shown you what to install:

```
apt-cache search synaptics
```

Comment: It works...Thanks :)...I would vote up your answer but I need more reputation :(